# JQuery плагин DataTable вопрос с AJAX

Tags: jquery, плагин, datatable, lazyloading, ajax-load

В данном плагине присутствуют паддинги и они считаются от кол-ва строк, но если у меня 100к данных в бд - это глупо выполнять 1 запрос и рендерить страницу в плане оптимизаций. Есть ли возможность эти паддинги вывести статично зная заранее сколько будет данных. Например я сделаю запрос в бд на кол-во строк и уже буду ориентироваться сколько мне нужно паддингов и при нажатий на следующий пункт выполнять запрос в бд на получение данных. Т.е сделать подобие ленивой загрузки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сторону https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если решать проблему не через serverside, то можно запрашивать на бэке общее кол-во строк,
задавать [кол-во страниц,](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len())
затем забирать с бэка данные в рамках этого пейджа и [добавлять строки руками](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()).
Но возможна проблема с сортировкой, поиском...поэтому, если есть возможность, лучше через serverside, ссылку вам уже дали в комментарии.